# TypeError: 'str' object is not callable - Python

Tags: python, string

I keep getting this error. TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

I searched all my code and I don't even use the word str anywhere.

```
if again():
        print ('%s LAST: %s') % (k, tx)
        m = 1
        k = 0.001
        amount = k / 0.00000001
        amount = int(amount)
        print ('Doing %s k') % k
        do(amount, int(m))   # The error occurs here
else:
     #code
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You assigned a string to `do` somewhere.

You'll need to search your code to see where you do that, or rename the `do()` function to something else to resolve the conflict.

Comment: Could be to `int` but highly unlikely giving the presence of `int(amount)` two lines up.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: No, because the error happens on the `do()` line, not 2 lines earlier where `int()` is also used.

Comment: In my world I take nothing for granted, could be multithreaded :) but I agree, this is `do`.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: Exactly, it's not as if the use of `int()` is conditional there.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: In the world of Python beginners of Stack Overflow, most don't use threading. :-)

Comment: I'll bite: In the world of programming, doing multithreading, who is not a beginner? ;)

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: :-) Tim Peters would be my first guess, as far as the Python world is concerned anyway.

Comment: Ok, I assigned "do" to a string up in the code. Thanks Martijn.