# Previous solutions doesn't work: TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Tags: python, xml, urllib

I know similar error has been reported, but I checked all online solutions and none of them work. So I decided to open a new post.
I was running the following code from an online course. It is supposed to work, however, it always reports the following error when running on my machine:

```
----> 7     input_str = input('Enter location: ')
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Below is the whole block of code:

```
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

serviceurl = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?'

while True:
    input_str = input('Enter location: ')
    if len(input_str) < 1: break

    url = serviceurl + urllib.parse.urlencode({'address': input_str})
    print('Retrieving', url)
    uh = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    data = uh.read()
    print('Retrieved', len(data), 'characters')
    print(data.decode())
    tree = ET.fromstring(data)

    results = tree.findall('result')
    lat = results[0].find('geometry').find('location').find('lat').text
    lng = results[0].find('geometry').find('location').find('lng').text
    location = results[0].find('formatted_address').text

    print('lat', lat, 'lng', lng)
    print(location)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you assign to `input` in your code?

Comment: @JaredSmith I'm not sure I understand your question.Do you mind explainning more? All my code is shown here. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: 'str' object is not callable - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22721671/typeerror-str-object-is-not-callable-python)

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error with the code you posted. However, Python will happily let you overwrite built-ins `input = 'explode my program'` then when you try to call input as a function you'll get that error you posted. Check the linked duplicate.

Comment: @JaredSmith The above code is copied from an online course, so it is supposed to be correct. However, it shows the above error in my machine. I won't be surprised if you cannot reproduce the error, but I'm so confused why it doesn't work on my machine. I'm using Python 3 and my other python code works well.

Comment: What does `type(input)` show?

Comment: @DyZ It shows 'str'.

Comment: @CathyQian open a terminal, type 'python3' without the quotes, and type 'type(input)' without the quotes. It should say `<class 'builtin_function_or_method'>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You redefined the built-in function `input` to a string *somewhere* in your code (not necessarily in the posted code fragment) by executing *something like this*:

```
input = ....
```

There is only one way to fix this error: close the Python interpreter and start it over again. Make sure that any code you execute does not contain assignments to `input` or any other identifiers that refer to the built-in functions.

Comment: Thanks! I realized indeed that I have a parameter called 'input' in my previous code as a string type. I was using Jupyter Notebook, so I closed it and reopen it. Problem solved! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score -3):

I see you're trying to put a string in "input_str". Have you already tried?:

```
input_str = raw_input('Enter location: ')
```

This type of method recieves a string as a input. The input of the method "input" must be a number

Regards!

Comment: Python3 has no raw_input.

Comment: Yes. But 2.7 does. That's why I said that

Answer (score -4):

Have you tried renaming the variable? Instead of input_str, try something like user_input. I'm pretty sure that 'str' is reserved in Python and so using it as a variable won't work.

Comment: Yes I have tried other names such as 'people', 'address' and they didn't work.

Comment: Did you actually try that before posting it as an answer?

Comment: @CathyQian that was directed at Andrew Grass. Typically we expect people to give authoritative answers, speculation isn't really a good answer.

Comment: You're right @JaredSmith , my bad. I'm new here. Thanks for the feedback.