# TypeError: 'str' object is not callable when using input() in PyDev for Eclipse

Tags: python, string, input, typeerror, pydev

[A similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22721671/typeerror-str-object-is-not-callable-python)

I'm making a basic text adventure game for the first time in PyDev in Eclipse and when I try to have the user give input more than once I get the above error.  Below is the code I used that generated the error:

```
print("Input a name for your character.")    
input = input()    
player = Character(input)
```

I already have the class `Character` defined and it takes a `str` as its argument. The setter is below.

```
player.setName(input)    
print("\nWelcome, "+input+"!\nChoose a weapon from the list below.")    
print("\nfists\ndagger\nspear\naxe\nshortsword\nlongsword\nmace")    
wpn = input()
```

I get a `TypeError` on the line with `wpn = input()`" saying `'str' object is not callable`.

This confuses me because, shouldn't this take input and store it in a new variable "wpn" where once it was stored in "input"? When I change wpn to input it works, but not if I ask it to take user input...

I want unique user inputs each time, but I'm not sure how to accomplish that given this error.

Comment: You assigned the user's input to the variable `input`.  After that point, you can no longer call `input()`, because that name no longer refers to the built-in function.  Just choose a different variable name there.

Answer (score 0):

You've changed input to be a string. It's no longer what the original input function does. Give the value that input returns a different name:

```
user_input = input()
```

This will keep the `input` function as it is.

Answer (score 0):

It is not working because your variable `input` is overwriting the real `input` function, so the best way to solve this is to rename the variable, try this:

```
user_input = input()
```

Now it won't overwrite the function