# Python Error Message: TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Tags: python

```py
num1 = input("Enter your first number: ")
operator = input("Enter +, *, +, or -")
num2 = input("Enter your second number: ")
if operator("+"):
    print(num1 + num2)
```

Very new to Python and coding in general so please excuse it if the error is very simple.

Comment: `operator('+')`? `operator` is a string. And for checking equality use `==`. `if operator == '+'`

Comment: num1 is not visible. There is no visible conversion (to int?) for num2. Operator is a variable, not a function, better use ==.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: 'str' object is not callable - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22721671/typeerror-str-object-is-not-callable-python)

Comment: @nilleb `TypeError` is raised because OP is using a `str` as function. And `num1+num2` works fine `str` supports `+` but it is used for concatenation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change

```
if operator("+"):
   print(num1 + num2)
```

to

```
if operator == "+":
    print(int(num1) + int(num2))
```

The operator is a string and to check if a string is equal to a value in python you use `==`. 
And the num1 and num2 the return from the input as a string so the add them as numbers you need to cast them to int.